# Return all instance one variables in one call

Tags: java

I have this class that serves as a container which I will use the instance variable for processing later

```
class Data{
    static int counter= 0;
    boolean boolean1;
    String string1;

    public Data() {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And I have this method that sets the values of Data

```
public Data setData()
{
    Data data = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < somecoutnerhere; i++) {

        Data = new Data();
        Data.boolean1 = some boolean put here;
        Data.string1 = "some string to be put here";
    }

    return ProcessData(Data);
}
```

I also have this class ProcessData that will make use of Data and will construct the response

```
private class ProcessData
{        
    private final Map<String, List<?>> map = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    int counter;

    public ProcessData(Data data)   
    {
        map.put("boolean1", data.boolean1);
        map.put("String1", data.string1);
        counter = data.counter;
    }

     public String someMethodToGenerateReturnData(){
     // some code here to make use of the Data collected. Will basically use map to construct the return String
     }
 }
```

My problem is that I couldn't figure out how can I return all the instance variables created on the for-loop for Data on setData(). Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use reflection to get all instance variables, but it is unclear why you need this

Comment: Depends on the need... you could use a List/array/set/collection to store all the result of ProcessData. Here, you lose every instance of Data except the last one of the loop ... so what are you doing exactly ?

Comment: Just put the data created in your for-loop into a list & return that? As of now, all you do is instantiating a new Data-object, filling it with data, and then overwriting it again and again.

Comment: Does your example even compile? I see multiple errors like wrong variable name, wrong data type in your map.put()

Comment: I'm just looking for a different approach. Reflection would be rather unnecessarily complicated but it would work. Already have a working version using collection; just had a thought if this would be possible.

Comment: Consider using a `List<Data>`.

Comment: *"Does your example even compile?"* - No it doesn't.  And since it doesn't compile, it is hard to figure out what the OP actually trying to do here.  For a start, I can't figure out whether `return ProcessData(Data);` is supposed to be a constructor or method call ... and what it is supposed to be returning.

Comment: Sorry, it should've been a constructor call

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that I couldn't figure out how can I return all the instance variables created on the for-loop for Data on setData(). Any thoughts?

According to this your problem is not "returning all instance one variables in one call", as your title states, but rather a question about how returning all `Data`-Objects created in your for-loop, which is easier.

Your code is erronous though, so I went ahead & corrected it (I hope I didn't mess up). I also renamed a few things.

The changes I made are:

- renamed "boolean1" and "string1" to "trueOrFalse" and "string"
- added a public, fully parameterized constructor to the `Data`-class
- added a `ProcessData`-list to the `setData()`-method, which is filled in the `for`-loop
  (+ a comment)

However, I'd strongly recommend you to check your architecture, and also to learn a bit about naming conventions, or coding conventions in general. Names should point out the purpose or content of the method/variable/class, and "boolean1" isn't really doing that.

Regarding the architecture: The `Data`-class seems to exist solely for the counter, and you could easily change that, making the `Data`-class obsolete (unless it's used somewhere else).

**Data class:**

```
class Data {
    static int counter = 0;
    boolean trueOrFalse;
    String string;

    public Data() {
        counter++;
    }

    public Data(boolean someBoolean, String someString) {
        this.trueOrFalse= someBoolean;
        this.string = someString;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**`setData()`-Method:**

```
public List<ProcessData> setData() {
    List<ProcessData> processedDataList = new ArrayList<ProcessData>();

    for (int i = 0; i < someCounterHere; i++) {
        processedDataList.add(new ProcessData(new Data(true, "testString"));
        // a new Data-object is created (parameters true and "testString")
        // a new ProcessData-object is created (parameter is the newly created Data-Object)
        // the newly created ProcessData-object is added to the list 
    }

    return processedDataList;
}
```

**`ProcessData`-class:**

```
private class ProcessData {        
    private final Map<String, List<?>> map = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    int counter;

    public ProcessData(Data data) {
        map.put("trueOrFalse", data.trueOrFalse);
        map.put("string", data.string);
        counter = data.counter;
    }

    public String someMethodToGenerateReturnData() {
    // some code here to make use of the Data collected. Will basically use map to construct the return String
    }
}
```